# How insert a form data to mysql when checkbox is checked?

Tags: mysql, checkbox, insert

Welcome, 
I have some problem with form and insert data to mysql.
My form have an input:

```
<inpu type="checkbox" name="check">
```

and this is my code to insert this form data to mysql.

```
if(isset($_POST['check'])) { //things to insert }
```

and when i select one checkbox code inserting every record, when i select all checkboxes its also inserting a every record (all data). But when i not select a checkbox insert is empty (good).
Whats wrong with this checkboxes?

Comment: sorry for my english :-)

Comment: you should probably provide more code, a small example where we can see more than one record and how your php script handle those.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are sent via POST only if checked. If they are unchecked, they are not sent. Maybe you expect value 'on' if checked, and value 'off' if unchecked, but no!, you will receive only 'on' if checked, nothing otherwise. So if you receive checkbox (check it with isset($_POST['checkbox_name']') variable in your post set 1, true, 'Y' or whatever you use for boolean value in your database. If you do not receive it !isset() then set 0, false, or 'N'. The same situation is with disabled INPUT elements. Their values are not sent t server.

```
<form action"processor.php" method="post">
  <input name="data[]"><input type="checkbox" name="check[]">
  <input name="data[]"><input type="checkbox" name="check[]">
  <input name="data[]"><input type="checkbox" name="check[]">
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

In your processor.php file:

```
 $data=$_POST['data']; //array received
 $checks=$_POST['check']; //array received (checked only)
 foreach($checks as $key=>$check) //loop through all checks that are sent
 {
   $value=$data[$key]; //do whatever you want with corresponding data
 }
```

Comment: could you write me how to change value of input in php / on my example?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve with your checkboxes. You speak about data you want to insert, checkboxes bring only boolean value 'on' or 'off'. What data you want to store?

Comment: i want to insert a record (id, event_id, name, start_time) to mysql. thats it. but only those records that are selected by input checkbox.